# Windows Phone Emulator wont run corrrectly

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

Facing a strange Problem...

In Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate my Phone App Builds correctly, i can deploy it to my device, but when deploying to the Emulator the XDE Pops up and says "Windows Phone OS is starting...".

I can see in the HyperV Manager that the OS Runs in Hyper-V, but the Emulator doesnt Show the Output and thus is no Debugging possible.

Have deinstalled VS2013 completely, restarted, new freshly installed.. no changes...

No error Messages.. nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to install the latest quarterly updated for visual studio 2013. I ran into a problem with the emulator (VS2012) when I installed the Azure toolkit which clobbered the quarterly update with similar problem as a symptom. Had to reapply (fix) the quarterly update.

Answer (score 0):

close your emulator and delete the snapshot that is in the hyper-V manager

run the emulator again and see if it is working appropriately

(The snapshot, in this case holds the bad response of the emulator. once you delete it and run the emulator, it again reforms to hold the actions where the emulator could work properly)